# The math behind Variance Shadow Maps - moments

Tags: mathematics, shaders, rendering, shadows, shadow-mapping

I am not asking how to implement them (that's not particularly difficult), but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding *why* [the moments used in Chebyshev's inequality](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch08.html) (indirectly) are equal to the *depth* value and the *depth* squared respectively.

To grasp why things are like this, I tried to understand what the random variable one computes the moments for is, and what is its density (the `p(x)` in those integrals used to compute the moments). Now that one can equate the moments to the depth and depth^2 is the *magic* behind this approach, hence the key of justifying it mathematically. Can anyone please explain what `p(x)` is, and why is the first moment equal to the `depth` value? I can probably pick up from there and easily understand the second moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p(x) there is the blur kernel, usually a Gaussian, with which you convolve the depth and depth^2 buffers.  (Or if you don't do a Gaussian blur on the VSM, then it's just the bilinear filtering kernel.)  The random variable is, correspondingly, the depth of a random point in the shadow map chosen with a Gaussian distribution around the point whose shadow you're evaluating.

I think the notation in the article is misleading because it makes it appear the integrals are one-dimensional, but in fact they are two-dimensional, done over the blur kernel's support in the shadow map's UV space.

Comment: thanks. I also figured they were talking about double integrals, but computer science papers usually abuse formulas on a regular basis. What you're saying really explains a lot.. this approach can be used for basically anything (not just depths), if `p(x)` is the convolution kernel.. leaving you with a nifty trick for soft feature representation. Thanks again..